# Multithreaded i += 1 has different behavior between Windows and Linux?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading

BASE = 1000000

i = 0

def test():
    global i
    for x in range(BASE):
        i += 1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=test) for t in range(10)]
for t in threads:
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

assert i == BASE*10, (BASE*10, i)
```

The code above can always pass on Windows but always fails on Linux. Why? Shouldn't they have the same behavior?

I expected both Windows and Linux to fail the test cause `i += 1` is not an atomic operation.

Is Windows passing the test a coincidence or there is something different between Windows and Linux?

Comment: Probably a Python version thing, not an OS thing. One of the recent-ish Python versions changed the logic for GIL releasing. Don't count on it - none of this is guaranteed, and especially with [the Python dev team pushing to remove the GIL entirely](https://discuss.python.org/t/a-steering-council-notice-about-pep-703-making-the-global-interpreter-lock-optional-in-cpython/30474), this is likely to change again. ("Long-term (probably 5+ years), the no-GIL build should be the only build.")

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, it's never used. I deleted it yet.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, you're right, it is just a Python version thing. I use Python3.11.4 can pass the test on Windows. But I downloaded Python2.7.5 on Windows and run the code again, it failed!

Comment: @user2357112 The version which failed on Linux was 3.8.5. It seems Python3.10.12 and Python3.11.4 can pass the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior is the same on all platforms and all releases: undefined ;-)

CPython's strategy for releasing the GIL is an implementation detail, and has changed several times over the years. In early days, it used to switch threads every `N` (which was configurable) trips around the interpreter's eval loop. Later, since opcodes can take vastly different amounts of time, every `S` (also configurable) microseconds or so instead. As of 3.11.3 (which is current as I type - I don't know when it was introduced), it's additionally only checked after certain *specific* opcodes are executed. This includes backward jumps (needed to form a loop) and most calls.

For an exact accounting, search for instances of the `CHECK_EVAL_BREAKER` macro in `Python/bytecodes.c`. But don't expect to understand them. Even if you do, it's all subject to change at any time.

In your code,

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(test)
  8           0 RESUME                   0

 10           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + range)
             14 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (BASE)
             26 PRECALL                  1
             30 CALL                     1
             40 GET_ITER
        >>   42 FOR_ITER                12 (to 68)
             44 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

 11          46 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (i)
             58 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             60 BINARY_OP               13 (+=)
             64 STORE_GLOBAL             2 (i)
             66 JUMP_BACKWARD           13 (to 42)

 10     >>   68 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             70 RETURN_VALUE
```

the stretch from `STORE_FAST 0 (x)` through `STORE_GLOBAL 2 (i)` doesn't contain one of those opcodes, so the GIL will not be released while that stretch is executing. That stretch is effectively atomic.

To see the kinds of races you expected, for now you would need to change the code to generate a "do a GIL check!" kind of opcode between the load of `i` and the store of `i+1`. For example, add the do-nothing function:

```
def f():
    pass
```

and change the loop body to

```py
        i1 = i + 1
        f()
        i = i1
```

The interpreter will then do a "time to swtich threads?" check when it hits the `CALL` opcode for the call to `f()`. Here's typical output then:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    assert i == BASE*10, (BASE*10, i)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AssertionError: (10000000, 4021380)
```

But if you comment out the call to `f()`, it will go back to not failing.

Comment: Thank you, I do understand. It is a Python version thing: 1. In some old version of Python like 3.8.5, `i += 1` **is not** an ATOMIC operation, because GIL may change every `N` trips. 2. But in newer versions of Python like 3.11.4, `i += 1` **is** a ATOMIC operation because there's no specific opcodes in it.